# Find the number of lattice squares intersected by the boundary

Tags: geometry

> Find the number of lattice squares that the curve $x^2+y^2 = 20.05^2$ intersects.

The solution guide says that we should look at one sector of the circle to see that it goes up $20$ and over $20$ so it should intersect a total of $4(20+20+1)$. On the surface this seems correct but can someone provide more proof for it and a picture?

Answer (score 2):

There are two keys.  The statement that you should just look at the first quadrant comes from the fact that all the powers of $x,y$ are even, so if $(x,y)$ is in one lattice square, $(-x,y), (x,-y), (-x,-y)$ satisfy the equation and are in the corresponding lattice squares.  The second is that the curve does not pass through any lattice points. A figure is below with $x^2+y^2=3.2^2$ and the grid lines shown. Starting from $(3.2,0)$ and going around to $(0,3.2)$ you cross $3$ horizontal and $3$ vertical grid lines, so change grid squares $6$ times, so touch $7$ grid squares.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$x^2+y^2=\left(\dfrac{81}4\right)^2\iff16x^2+16y^2=81^2$$

Observe that if  $f(x,y)=16x^2+16y^2, f(\pm x,\pm y)$ are same

So we can focus on $0\le16x^2\le81^2$ with $x\ge0$ as $16y^2\ge0$

$\implies0\le x\le\sqrt{\dfrac{81^2}{16}}<411$