# Ideas on how to find the number of unit cubes that intersect ball with radius R

Tags: calculus, geometry

I'm having trouble figuring how what it means for integer unit cubes to intersect a ball with radius R. So I'm given that we're working in $\mathbb{R}^2$ so our ball is a circle, and our integer unit cube are squares. Here are my questions.

1. If this ball is centered at the origin, what does it mean for an integer unit cube to intersect that ball? Sorry if this is obvious.
2. Is it difficult to find the number of unit cubes that intersect this ball at radius R? I was trying an induction argument with the first quadrant, but didn't get anywhere. Please provide a hint because I still want to figure the bulk of it out.
3. Would doing the same for a sphere be that much more difficult?

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: This question asked the same, at least for the 2d case: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1590190/find-the-number-of-lattice-squares-intersected-by-the-boundary

Comment: Oh, thanks a bunch! I could not find anything on it anywhere here...I'm going to work it out. I'm hoping the 3d case will be similar.

Comment: The 2d version of a *ball* would be a *disk*, i.e. a circle *and its interior*. A *circle* is usually just the line itself, and the arbitrary dimension of that is called a *(hyper)sphere*. The question @Aretino mentioned is talking about a circle, so it is not an exact match if you really want to consider a ball.