# Sphere in a regular grid, area formula

Tags: computer-science, euclidean-geometry

Usually, the formula for area of the sphere is $4 \pi r^2$.

My sphere is inside a regular cubic grid, with 1×1×1 unit size cells.

I’d like to know the count of the grid cells that happen to intersect with the surface of my sphere. I only need the approximate answer, for large values of $r$.

Intuitively, this going to be $4 \pi r^2 C$, where $C$ is some constant.

What’s the value of $C$?

Comment: My computations show that $C \rightarrow 1.5$ when $r\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: @Oleg567 Thanks a lot! My question is somewhat practical, so the 1.5 is good enough for me.

Comment: @Oleg567: Did you arrive at ${3\over2}$ via integral geometry or via numerical experiments?

Comment: [This person](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1908123/ideas-on-how-to-find-the-number-of-unit-cubes-that-intersect-ball-with-radius-r) was asking the same thing a year ago, no answers. There's a $3/2$ asymptotic factor in [this related OEIS](https://oeis.org/A085690)

Comment: @ChristianBlatter, I arrived $\frac{3}{2}$ via numerical experiments: just considered different $r$ and cubes with vertices $(a,b,c), \ldots, (a+1,b+1,c+1)$, where $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}$, and checked which of them intersect with the surface of the sphere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following heuristic makes the value $C={3\over2}$ plausible:

Consider a sphere $S_R$ of radius $R\gg1$. The lattice planes $x=j\in{\mathbb Z}$, $y=k$, or $z=l$ intersect $S_R$ in circles which together partition $S_R$ into a number of cells of various shapes. We have to estimate the number of these cells.

Looking from $(0,0,+\infty)$ down to $S_R$ we see about $\pi R^2$ unit squares. These are projections of quadrangles on $S_R$ produced by the planes $x=j$ and $y=k$, and there are another $\pi R^2$ such squares to be seen on the lower hemisphere.

The latitude circle $z=l$ has radius $r_l=\sqrt{R^2-l^2}$. It intersects about $2r_l$ planes $x=j$ and $2r_l$ planes $y=k$, generating about  $8r_l$ points of intersection. Each arc between two successive such points bisects an "$xy$-quadrangle", hence augments the number of cells by $1$. The total contribution obtained in this way is about
$$\sum_{l=-R}^R 8 r_l\doteq 4\sum_{l=-R}^R 2\sqrt{R^2-l^2}\doteq4\pi R^2\ ,$$
since the last sum is a Riemann sum for the area of a disc of radius $R$.

It follows that the total number of cells can be estimated as
$$2\pi R^2+4\pi R^2={3\over2}\cdot4\pi R^2\ .$$